# Django: FileField name special chars replaced automatically

Tags: django

My model:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="myfiles", max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

When file names contain special chars, such as ' '(space), special chars will be replaced by underscore automatically. 
**Where (in which function) does this happen?** How to disable this automatic validation?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Any comments on the following codes?** Thanks

```
"""
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/files/storage/#Storage.get_valid_name
Overwrite get_valid_name() function, 
"""
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage): 
    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        print "name=", name
        return name

class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="myfiles", max_length=500, storage=OverwriteStorage())
```

Comment: What kind of special char is that? Single quotes? Sometimes it's your shell that replaces those characters. It's like you `touch` a new file in your shell with special characters in the file name.

Comment: @ShangWang e.g. space

Comment: your solution is right if you only use it for one model, you might want to check my updated answer if you'd rather set it globally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your storage. `FileField` calls `storage.get_valid_name` on the storage ([ref](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L314)).

You can probably overwrite that function (depending on your storage), but I think it's probably better to leave it as it is. You can always use the name field.

If you use `FileSystemStorage`, it will call `django.utils.text.py`, which replaces the spaces with underscores ([ref](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py#L234)).

**Edit:**

Assuming you use the default `FileSystemStorage` here's how to override it:

create a file (probably in your main app)

storage.py:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class CustomFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        return name
```

(you might need the `@deconstructible` decorator for migrations)

Now you have two options to use this storage. You can either specify it in you models explicitly:

My model:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="myfiles", max_length=500, storage=CustomFileSystemStorage)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

Or you can set it globally in your `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '{yourapp}.storage.CustomFileSystemStorage'
```

([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE))

Comment: how to overwrite it? Any examples?

Comment: Here are the source files: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py  get_valid_name in Storage class (in the parent class of FileSystemStorage) uses the get_valid_filename function defined here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py The latter substitutes the spaces with underscores. In the example above we do not call the get_valid_filename function.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is in django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py#L234). I'm not really sure how to disable it though, why not leave it as it is?